# Find a basis of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $$
B = 
\pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0
}
$$

find a basis for the $im(B)$ and a basis for the $ker(B)$.

I know that a basis for the image will just be columns $1$ and $3$ in $B$, since they represent the nonredundant columns, but I'm having trouble find a basis for the $ker(B)$. I'm told that a basis for the $ker(B)$ is $\{\pmatrix{0\\
-1\\
0\\
0\\
},\pmatrix{1\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
} 
\}$, but I don't see why this is true.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of $B$ is the solution set to the system of equations $Bx=0$. Solve it, find that the general solution has two free parameters $s,t$ (in factor two of the four unknowns of the problem), which can be written as linear combination $s\vec v+t\vec w$ for certain vectors $\vec v,\vec w\in\Bbb R^4$. Then $[\,\vec v,\vec w]$ is a basis of $\ker B$. Depending on just how you solved the system, you might find a different pair of vectors than the proposed solution (a subspace has many possible bases).